# regular expression needed to remove C/C# comments

Tags: c#, regex

I need a C# regex to delete everything between `/*` and `*/` including the `/**/`.
So, basically remove all code comments in the given text.

Comment: you really don't need a regex for that.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: That is not that easy. Your code may contain strings like "This: /* boo */ is no comment".

Comment: Or commented comments: `// no comment here /*`, followed by `WillBeRemoved(); /* real comment */`. Ok, not too common, but you can get very creative with messing this up.

Comment: C# is not a *regular language*, so it is impossible to recognize it correctly with a *regular expression*. If you want to remove comments correctly then what you have to build is a *lexer*. Break the text up into tokens and identify which tokens are comments.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to remove comments in a piece of code.  Please do not make programmers in general look stupid by actually doing this.

Comment: @Eric - although they are certainly not the right tool for this job, .NET regular expressions are not limited to recognizing regular languages (e.g. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition).

Comment: @Ramhound: There are lots of reasons to remove comments. For example, when compressing code that is going to be delivered over a highly performance-sensitive channel where it's not going to be read by humans on the other end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
var regex = new Regex("/\*((?!\*/).)*\*/", RegexOptions.Singleline);

regex.Replace(input, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Be wary that comments can be nested. If comments can be nested like in SQL, the basic regex is going to look like this:

```
/\*.*?\*/
```

You'll then need to loop until you're stripping nothing.

If, by contrast, comments end on the first */ like in C, you need it greedy with a negative lookahead:

```
/\*((?!\*/).)*\*/
```

Comment: That doesn't work for multi-line comments, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was also needing to ignore lines comments with the form

```
// blablabla
```

So, just for if someone also need this, modify the regex by adding the last part **|(//.*)** so the complete form will be:

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```