# Extract comments from .cs file

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to use a Regular Expression to extract *only* comments from a C# file?

If so how would you do that?

Comment: For /*...*/ style comments, you could just invert the solution from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138296/regular-expression-needed-to-remove-c-c-comments - remember, the RegEx you use to replace comments can also be used to find them.

Answer (score 2):

[Refer this: -> Finding Comments in Source Code Using Regular Expressions](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html)

after reading the article, your final RegEx would be.

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

FOR C#

```
^/[/|*](.+)$ (for single line comment )
(^\/\/.*?$|\/\*.*?\*\/) (for multilne comments)
```

Comment: This is nice, but it would fail to find "single-line" comments that don't start at the beginning of the line. This is probably better accomplished with some type of parser/filter rather than a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This Regex finds all the comments in a C# file.

```
(((?<=//).+(?=\n))|((?<=/*)[^(\*/)]+(?=\*/)))+
```